# Test for two proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a question with three outcomes (yes, no, do not know) and observed probabilities p_yes, p_no and p_dontknow. How do I test that for the true probabilities pi_yes > pi_no holds? I think a two sample binomal test is not appropriate, since the sum of all probabilities is one.

Or could I just throw the dont know answers away and test if pi_yes* > 0.5 with a one sample binomial test?

Comment: If there are relatively few DK responses, it may be OK to ignore them. But if there are very many you should consider whether your questionnaire is measuring what you intended. (Does DK mean the question is too difficult, or that it is somehow controversial, embarrassing, politically charged, intrusive, would require info not immediately at hand, or not of personal interest, so that many users prefer to avoid the issue with DK?)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a mulitnomial outcome, the groups are not independent so I don't think a binomial test ignoring the third category would be best.

The data are multinomial with 3 categories.  This means that the estimates of the multinomial proportions $\boldsymbol{p}$ are $E(y_j) = y_j/n = p_j$ $$\boldsymbol{\Sigma}(\boldsymbol{p})=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
p_{1}\left(1-p_{1}\right) & -p_{1} p_{2} & -p_{1} p_{3} \\
-p_{1} p_{2} & p_{2}\left(1-p_{2}\right) & -p_{2} p_{3} \\
-p_{1} p_{3} & -p_{2} p_{3} & p_{3}\left(1-p_{3}\right)
\end{array}\right]$$

Because the proportions are constrained to sum to 1, $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ is degenerate and so the last column is superfluous.

I *think* that means we can leverage the fact that the sample mean is asymptotically normal to use the following test statistic

$$z = \dfrac{\sqrt{n}(p_1 - p_2)}{\sqrt{p_1(1-p_1) + p_2(1-p_2) -2p_1p_2}} $$

Here, I've used the fact that $\operatorname{Var}(p_1-p_2) = \operatorname{Var}(p_1) + \operatorname{Var}(p_2) - 2\operatorname{Cov}(p_1,p_2)$ all of which are available from the submatrix of $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}(\boldsymbol{p})$.

Some simulation shows that the false positve rate is just slightly above the nominal (but this is maybe just due to the sample size being relatively small).

```
z = replicate(100000,{
  #generate data
  x = rmultinom(100, 1, c(0.4, 0.4, 0.2))
  #estimate proportions
  p = apply(x, 1, mean)
  #get covariance matrix
  s = cov(t(x))[1:2, 1:2]
  # test statistic
  z = sqrt(100)*(p[1] - p[2])/ sqrt(s[1,1] + s[2,2] - 2*s[1,2])
  
  pnorm(abs(z), lower.tail = F)*2
  
})


mean(z<0.05)
>>>0.0543 # Depending on your random seed
```

But I would wait for someone else to double check me on this.